# Expression editor / parser / evaluator

Tags: c#, parsing, expression, editor, evaluator

I am trying to work on a C# project and I would like to allow the user to run code on the fly, by typing code into an editor.
So with that in mind, I thought about writing some sort of scripting editor, parser and evaluator, but wanted to check with other people first, in case I am just reinventing the wheel?

So, my idea is/was to...

1. Write a syntax highlighted editor that I can write code into,
   including the use of custom keywords.
2. Add logic to the editor so that it will be able to format the
   content based on the text in the editor.
3. Have a way of 'actioning' the text that has been entered.

For instance, if I enter the following...

```
if (Shape.IsACube())
{
  // Do some cube stuff
}
else if (Shape.Area(height, length, width) > 40)
{
  // Do some large area stuff
}
```

...then I would like to be able to run that code on the fly as though it was part of the application.

I hope all of that makes sense. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which grammar for your syntax you want to use? Your own or C# ?

Comment: Since we cannot add anymore answer in this topic, I will add it as a comment. Creating your compiler is a very big job, I suggest you to try some free library like (https://csharpeval.codeplex.com/) or my PRO library (http://eval-expression.net/) which support nearly everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which grammar for your syntax you want to use? Your own or C# ? 
If you just want to compile some C# code in runtime - you can use something like **CodeDOM**. Highlighting can be achieved through **C# Syntax Highlighter**.

If you want your own grammar with your terminals/non-terminals - you should use grammar makers like **ANTLR4**. This way you will understand how most compilers/interpretators works.

The main idea is that you write **Lexer** (which responsible for tokenization of your input) and **Parser** (which is actualy just list of grammar rules, 'productions' in other words). It will give you full AST from which you can evaluate/highlight your text. Many language grammars already written before you in **[here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4)** including C# syntax (even ANTLR4 itself is presented). So you can just pick some and modify it for your needs.

Comment: Hi eocron, and thank you for your valued input.

Comment: The grammar I will probably want to use will be my own but the more I think about it, most of it will probably be C#. I may also have a need where I would like to be able to step through the code one line at a time if that is possible, like a debug session, although I appreciate that will require more work and not be a straight compile of the code.

Comment: Then I suggest you to use ANTLR4 for this purpose. You can find C# grammar in repository and modify it to your needs. ANTLR4 basicaly, just creates parser/lexer classes, it does not compile them, it just generates them. Like WCF tools generate proxy classes for service. Step-through is a bit tricky though. You need some advanced runtime compiler for this, you can look at Roslyn compiler, though Im not sure it capable to step-through some C# string.